# Edit a file using sed/awk

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I have a file which contains the following data:

```
wednesday
Weekday

thursday
Weekday

friday
Weekday

saturday
MaybeNot

sunday
MaybeNot

monday
Weekday

tuesday
Weekday
```

I would like to insert a string `$:$` in front of each alternate line such that the file is rewritten as follows:

```
wednesday
$:$Weekday

thursday
$:$Weekday

friday
$:$Weekday

saturday
$:$MaybeNot

sunday
$:$MaybeNot

monday
$:$Weekday

tuesday
$:$Weekday
```

How would I achieve this using awk/sed?

Comment: So you want to prepend `$:$` to every 3rd line beginning with the second line?

Comment: @Thor - Essentially, yes.  Prepend `$:$` to the beginning of the second line of the file and then every third line from thereon.

Comment: In that case GNU sed has a good option, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok. here.

```
cat << EOF | awk -vRS="" '{print $1 "\n$:$" $2 "\n" }'       
wednesday
Weekday

thursday
Weekday

friday
Weekday

saturday
MaybeNot

sunday
MaybeNot

monday
Weekday

tuesday
Weekday
EOF
```

gives...

```
wednesday
$:$Weekday

thursday
$:$Weekday

friday
$:$Weekday

saturday
$:$MaybeNot

sunday
$:$MaybeNot

monday
$:$Weekday

tuesday
$:$Weekday
```

Comment: what does `-vRS=""` do?

Comment: It changes the record separator. Records are now separated by blank lines.

Comment: and if I want to do an in-place replacement within the file do I do it with this command `awk -vRS="" '{print $1 "\n$:$" $2 "\n" }' filename` ?

Comment: hmmm, don't know. in-place isn't available until gawk 4.1. awk is different.

Answer (score 1):

If your file doesn't start with a newline and has newlines as shown in your question then use:

```
sed -i.bak '2s/^/$.$/;3,${n;n;s/^/$.$/;}' file
```

If file has no new lines and **you want to put `$.$` before every alternate line** as you state in question:

```
sed -i.bak 'n;s/^/$.$/' file
```

Comment: The file doesn't begin with a newline.

Comment: Ok in that case I edited my answer. First sed should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

To prepend `$:$` to every 3rd line starting with line 2 do this with GNU sed:

```
sed -i '2~3s/^/$:$/' infile
```

Note that this will overwrite `infile` so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk - the variable `n` is initialised in the BEGIN pattern, then the lines are printed as required by testing the odd/eveness of `n`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=1}
{
     if (n++ % 2)
       print $0
     else
       print "$:$"$0
}' datafile
```

Comment: Your awk gives
`$:$wednesday
$:$Weekday
$:$
$:$thursday
$:$Weekday
$:$
$:$friday
$:$Weekday
$:$
$:$saturday
$:$MaybeNot
$:$
$:$sunday
$:$MaybeNot
$:$
$:$monday
$:$Weekday
$:$
$:$tuesday
$:$Weekday`

Here is another version based on your idea.
`awk 'NR%3==2 {$0="$:$"$0} 1'`

Answer (score 0):

ssed use perlre, so if you know perlre, it simple. use -i if you want modify target file.

```
cat t|ssed 's/^\([A-Z]\)/$:$&/'

wednesday

$:$Weekday

thursday

$:$Weekday


friday

$:$Weekday

saturday

$:$MaybeNot

sunday

$:$MaybeNot

monday

$:$Weekday

tuesday
$:$Weekday
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^[[:upper:]]/ {$0="$:$"$0}1' file
```

to replace in the file

```
awk '/^[[:upper:]]/ {$0="$:$"$0}1' file > tmp ; mv tmp file
```

**EDIT**
Another version (this needs the formatting to be the same all time):

```
awk 'NR%3==2 {$0="$:$"$0} 1' file
```