# Replace string if first letter is uppercase using sed

Tags: regex, sed, cygwin

I try to write sed answer to this question [Edit a file using sed/awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372796/edit-a-file-using-sed-awk) using:

```
sed -e 's/^[A-Z]/$:$&/' file.txt
```

but the result is:

```
wednesday
$:$Weekday

$:$thursday
$:$Weekday

$:$friday
$:$Weekday

$:$saturday
$:$MaybeNot

$:$sunday
$:$MaybeNot

$:$monday
$:$Weekday

$:$tuesday
$:$Weekday
```

Why it replace if first character is lower case?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Are you sure you didn't add a case-insensitive option?

Comment: @Barmar no, I use the exact command, but I'm using cygwin.

Comment: It works correctly on Linux and OS X. Sounds like a problem with the Cygwin version of sed.

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372796/edit-a-file-using-sed-awk ?

I had suggest you use ssed which can use perlre.

Comment: @Barmar Seems it's not a bug per se, see the links I provided below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "feature" according to [this bug report](http://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin/2013-06/msg00633.html) caused by unexpected character ordering in the locale, further explained [here](http://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin/2013-06/msg00645.html) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges-and-Locales.html).

```
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

$ echo "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | sed -e 's/[A-Z]/./g'
..........................a.........................

$ echo "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | sed -e 's/[a-z]/./g'
.........................Z..........................

$ echo "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | LC_ALL=C sed -e 's/[A-Z]/./g'
..........................abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

$ echo "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | LC_ALL=C sed -e 's/[a-z]/./g'
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ..........................

$ echo "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | sed -e 's/[[:upper:]]/./g'
..........................abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

$ echo "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | sed -e 's/[[:lower:]]/./g'
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ..........................

$ sed --version
GNU sed version 4.2.1
```

Comment: @Thor: On Linux it works, the question is about a Cygwin environment (see tags).

Comment: Updated my answer with links to explanations of this ("correct") range behaviour.